# Find the TreeNode at a certain Point

Tags: java, swing, jtree, mouselistener

I have a `JTree` with a `MouseListener` for Right-click detection. When the user clicks, I get a `MouseEvent` containing the source, the `Jtree`.

How can I get the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` right-clicked?

I thought about getting the Node at the `Point` presented in `mouseEvent.getLocationOnScreen()` but I don't know how

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`JTree#getClosestPathForLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getClosestPathForLocation%28int,int%29) method

Comment: Thanks. just one question, Should i use the relative X (`mouseEvent.getX()`) or the onscreen X (`mouseEvent.getXOnScreen()`) ?

Comment: @AdelBoutros Normally coordinates relatively to the JTree (so upper left corner of the `JTree` is located at (0,0) )

Comment: @Adel Boutros depends of Containers/Components hierarchy, maybe SwingUtilities is another way ho to ...